# Does Npgsql support projection queries?

Tags: entity-framework, npgsql

If I do this...

```
Context.Orders.Select(o => o.User.UserId);
```

... I get an exception because `User` is null. I can use `Include` instead,

```
Context.Orders.Include(o => o.User).Select(o => o.User.UserId);
```

... but shouldn't `User` be loaded automatically?

**EDIT:**

The first snippet of code doesn't work when the `Select` is applied to the result of a function. Which type should the function return in order to tack the `Select` onto the database query?

I've tried `IEnumerable<Order>` and `IQueryable<Order>`.

Comment: `Include` is ignored in projection queries. Are you sure the first query (**exactly** as it is) generates NRE? Because if that's true, it definitely is a bug.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've updated the question.

Comment: The source of the query should be `IQueryable<Order>` and must be real, i.e. not some fake LINQ to Objects `IEnumerable<Order>` converted with `AsQueryable()`

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh yes, it does seem to work. Thank you for your reality check.

Comment: You are welcome mate, glad it helped. Cheers.